# What are the advantages of Mac OS X vs. Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mac

I mainly use gVim, terminal and Firefox. Currently I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed on my Mac, but I am wondering if I should install Mac OS X 10.6, as I just found my original disk. Would I gain anything by moving to OS X? Would I lose any of the functionality for the tools I mentioned? How does OS X's terminal compare to Ubuntu's? Is there a tool which is fully compatbile with gVim?

Comment: you wiped out your macos to use gvim, firefox and a terminal? :=)

Comment: why did you buy a mac if it is not to run MacOSX ?

Comment: I edited your post fairly heavily, as it was at risk for being closed as subjective and argumentative. I believe the edit emphasized your actual core question, and made the question more concise, clear, and in-line with [SuperUser's guidelines](http://superuser.com/faq). If you have any questions, please respond in the comments. Good luck finding a quality solution to your questions!

Comment: Louis, superior hardware, battery, visual appeal.

Comment: @mattcodes: the hardware at the same machine is the same, no matter what OS you run.

Comment: akira, try dropping an asus/acer/hp/lenova, spilling a beer over it, dragging round the world without a case, getting sand in it, bumping it daily, and it still work flawlessly, any other laptop would be in the e.g. lenovo toughbook range - at which point costs more than a macbook.

Comment: @akira, have a look at the new MacBook Air...

Comment: @macbook, @Thorbjorn: i have no clue what you are talking about. OP owns a mac, so discussing the advantages of HARDWARE over XYZ is completely out of scope here. i never said anything pro or against a macbook, so i have absolutely no idea of what your arguments are about.

Comment: on the whole, there are no advantages, ubuntu wins out..but the illusion created by apple is very difficult to separate from, and  ppl argue for mac...

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/4886/ubuntu-vs-mac-os

Answer (score 3):

you will use [macvim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/), firefox binaries and most likely [iterm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/).

you will have the same toolset as you have in linux plus the ability to write stuff for iphone/ipod/ipad. you will lose the ability to put write your own kernel module. you will gain a system you do not have to take care about a lot. you will lose a system which you can fine tune to infinity and learn new things / waste a lot of time (point of view). you will gain carefree backup (timemachine), you will lose fiddling around with btrfs snapshots. you will gain [steam](http://store.steampowered.com/), you will gain macports and you will lose apt-get.

i, personally, would use mac osx. as soon as i would hit a wall  with what mac osx provides i would install a virtual machine and put there the linux / unix i would need to do the devel stuff. i do not expect that wall to occur very soon.

Comment: Is MacVIM fully compatible?

Comment: yes, otherwise the whole project would be pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You  can install OS X and then use Bootcamp to dual-install Ubuntu.  You can then switch between the two as you like.

Comment: dualbooting is such a pita and should be avoided. running some apps (mostly games) under the native os is ok, but linux/bsd runs just fine under any virtual machine.

Comment: @akira, depends on what you need.   There is insufficient data to say for sure that the OP's needs are 100% identical to yours.